# append a GET variable to a link when clicked

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have URL such as:

```
<a href="images.php?id=15645" rel="gallery">
```

There is already a click handler on this URL (FancyBox lightbox gallery):

```
$('a[rel=gallery]').fancybox();
```

I would like to append another GET variable to this URL (`title="mytitle"`), but ONLY when it is clicked. The GET variable must not be displayed to the user in the status bar (at the point the link is clicked or afterwards when hovering over that same link). Basically the GET variable doesn't actually get added to the link, it just gets "sent" with the request.

Comment: I hope you're not depending on GET variables being securely hidden from a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rCXu5/):

html

```
<a href="images.php?id=15645" rel="gallery">example</a>
```

JS:

```
var 
    agallery = $('a[rel=gallery]'),
    orig = "";

var onstart = function() {
    agallery.attr('href', function(i, a) { orig = a; return (a +'&title="mytitle"'); });

};

var onend = function() {
    agallery.attr('href', orig);
};

$('a[rel=gallery]').fancybox({
    onStart: onstart,
    onComplete: onend,
    onCancel: onend
});
```

Comment: Hi Andres, thanks for this. One question though - when does the onCancel event get called? I would presume it's when the user hits the escape button, or stops the image loading in some other way. As a test I clicked a thumbnail and immediately pressed the escape button. The image didn't load up but when I hovered over the thumbnail it still had the new GET parameter in its URL. Any ideas?

Comment: Also does this work for multiple links, i.e. with the same "rel" attribute?

Comment: I do not know when you run the event "onCancel"but I came to see that what seemed to me appropriate to include the function for this event.

How are the other links you have on your page?

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done, GET variables are passed via a URL. You'd need to pass them via POST to hide them from the URL bar, but even then anyone can see what is being submitted.

Comment: Not necessarily. By the sounds of things, fancybox is loading whatever the href of the link is using GET through AJAX. This won't appear in the URL bar since the user stays on the same page.